# How to call a friend operator overload function?

Tags: c++

```
class Sale
{
   void Display();
```

I can call it in another file, let say register.cpp file as

```
something.Display();
```

How can I call Display() if were a friend operator<< function?

```
class Sale
{
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Song& s);
```

here is sale.cpp with ostream definition

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const Song& s)
{ //title, artist, category, and size are private member data of sale.h
    os << s.title << "\t" << s.artist
       << "\t" << s.category << "\t" << s.size;
}
```

Display() definition is hard-coded to cout

My assignment also requires me to call the operator<< in register.cpp file
to do the same thing as Display()

How can I do it?

Comment: If Display is hardcoded to output text to the console, you can't output it to the stream.

Comment: Functions are called the same regardless of whether they have friend access or not. What are you asking?

Comment: @NeilKirk might be on the right idea... You could implement `Display` in terms of `operator<<` but not the other way.